# Rest High Level Client : Request timeout is not working

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-high-level-restclient

We are trying to use a request timeout in our queries but it doesn't seem to be working for us.

Here're the things we have done as part of setup:

- search.default_allow_partial_results : false (on server side as well
  as client side)
- Set the timeout of 10ms in every search query that we hit. (client
  side)
- Apart from these, we have global timeouts set as shown in the code
  below:

```
RestHighLevelClient client = new 
RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(httpHost).setRequestConfigCallback(
    requestConfigBuilder -> requestConfigBuilder
    .setConnectTimeout(30000)
    .setConnectionRequestTimeout(90000)
    .setSocketTimeout(90000)).setMaxRetryTimeoutMillis(90000));
```

Queries are taking more than 8 seconds but still not getting timed out. We have disabled the partial results as an expectation to get a timeout error but we don't get any error as well.

Also, the isTimedOut flag is returned as false always even though query took more than the specified timeout.

Here's a sample of request that I'm querying:

```
SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();

    BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
    QueryBuilder infraQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.termQuery("field1", field1);
    QueryBuilder totalCountRangeQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("field2").gte(3);

    BoolQueryBuilder innerBoolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
    innerBoolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("nestedDocType1.field1").gt(2));

    QueryBuilder filter = QueryBuilders
        .nestedQuery("nestedDocType1", innerBoolQueryBuilder, ScoreMode.Max)
        .innerHit(new InnerHitBuilder()
            .setFetchSourceContext(
                new FetchSourceContext(true, new String[]{"nestedDocType1.field1"}, null))
            .addSort(SortBuilders.fieldSort("nestedDocType1.field1").order(SortOrder.DESC))
            .setSize(1)
        );

    boolQueryBuilder.must(infraQueryBuilder);
    boolQueryBuilder.must(totalCountRangeQueryBuilder);

    if (inputRevisions != null && (inputRevisions.size() > 0)) {
      QueryBuilder allEligibleRevisionsFilter = QueryBuilders
          .termsQuery("field3", inputRevisions);
      boolQueryBuilder.must(allEligibleRevisionsFilter);
    }

    boolQueryBuilder.filter(filter);

    sourceBuilder.query(boolQueryBuilder)
        .fetchSource(new String[]{
            "field3",
            "field2"
        }, null);

    sourceBuilder.size(batchSize);
    sourceBuilder.timeout(TimeValue.timeValueMillis(10));

    SearchRequest searchRequest = createSearchRequest(sourceBuilder, enterpriseId);
    searchRequest.allowPartialSearchResults(false);

    SearchResponse searchResponse = getSearchResponse(searchRequest);

    ESCustomScroll<Set<String>> esCustomScroll = this::populateProcessedRevisionsSetWithESScroll;
    getESDataByScroll(esCustomScroll, searchResponse, processedRevisions);  // gets the data by scrolling over again and again until data is available.
```

Here's the code that we use for scrolling:

```
private boolean populateProcessedRevisionsSetWithESScroll(SearchResponse searchResponse, Set<String> processedRevisions) {
            if(searchResponse == null ||
                searchResponse.getHits() == null ||
                searchResponse.getHits().getHits() == null ||
                searchResponse.getHits().getHits().length == 0) {
              return false;
            }

            for(SearchHit outerHit : searchResponse.getHits().getHits()) {
              Map<String, Object> outerSourceMap = outerHit.getSourceAsMap();

              String revision = (String) outerSourceMap.get("field4");
              int totalCount = (Integer) outerSourceMap.get("field3");

              SearchHit[] innerHits = outerHit.getInnerHits().get("nestedDocType1").getHits();

              if(innerHits == null || innerHits.length == 0) {
                logger.error("No inner hits found for revision: "+revision);
                continue;
              }

              Map<String, Object> innerSourceMap = innerHits[0].getSourceAsMap();
              int simCount = (Integer) innerSourceMap.get("field1");

              if(((totalCount - simCount) == 0) || (simCount > ((totalCount - simCount) / 2))) {
                processedRevisions.add(revision);
              }
            }

            return true;
          }
```

Even in case of partial results, we expect the isTimedOut flag to be set. But that's not the case.

Can you please guide us where are we wrong or what are we missing?

Related question: [Java High Level Rest Client is not releasing connection although timeout is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59550811/java-high-level-rest-client-is-not-releasing-connection-although-timeout-is-set)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `setMaxRetryTimeoutMillis` for `RestClientBuilder` – it will create a listener and cut it off after `setMaxRetryTimeoutMillis` expires.